# How to display the PictureBox image into PDF file with the help of PDFsharp in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp

I'm developing a Windows application in c#. In my application I have developed PDF file with the help of PDFsharp. I have to display the image in the PDF file from the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the GDI+ of PDFsharp, you can simply call `XImage.FromGdiPlusImage`:

```
XImage img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(pb.Image);
```

`pb` is the PictureBox.

This answer is for PDFsharp.

Sample code that adds images to a PDF file using PDFsharp (demonstrating the use of the XImage class) can be found here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Images_35

Answer (score 0):

temperory save image to local disk and add to pdf document object (After creation of pdf doc you can delete image.)

sample code:

```
Bitmap bmpImage = null;
string strPdfDocSavePath = @"D:\Images\";
bmpImage = PctrBx.Image;
string strImageName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
bmpImage.Save(strPdfDocSavePath + @"\" + strImageName + ".bmp");

MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image img = row.Cells[0].AddImage(strPdfDocSavePath + @"\" + strImageName + ".bmp"); // Here i am using table for displaying image , add column and row to table, add image to desired cell
row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
img.LockAspectRatio = true;
img.WrapFormat.Style =MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.WrapStyle.Through;
img.Width = "7cm";
```

finally delete image after pdf creation

Comment: The question is tagged PDFsharp, the answer shows MigraDoc code.